# spring-mvc-404 page not found error in maven project

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have been trying to understand and clone the spring mvc login and registration process. As far as I know I am following the same code and process. Only thing I have changed is database details.0 Which works fine I am able to insert the data into the MySQL (8.0.27) database using test file. I am getting the same error even when I am trying his code I am getting error.

here is my code: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1JNkZp_O1Lh0y_1NdZ-A85KI1gfgy0_Em?usp=sharing

here is GitHub code: https://github.com/javabyranjith/spring-framework-mvc/tree/master/springmvc-userlogin

Errors I am getting:

1. action keyword in form was giving error "element loginProcess is not found"-> so I changed it to the form action then it worked
2. The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

my questions are

1. can a different version of Apache Tomcat(10.0.13) server can cause the issue?
2. since I am using new Eclipse so I have updated the new libraries can this cause the issues?

Please suggest the changes so that I can run this project. Suggest the changes here or directly change it in the google drive folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat 10 does not work with Spring 5. Downgrade to Tomcat 9.
10th has jakarta packages renamed from javax, which spring 5 does not support.

Friendly advice, if you are using code from git, they left versions of stuff like java and tomcat for a reason, and the newest versions like Tomcat 10 and JDK17 went through a lot of changes, so always try with suggested versions and try to migrate them to higher ones. Except for Tomcat 10, you will have to wait for Spring 6 for that.

As for the new eclipse, it does not make any difference, the maven project is still the maven project, src, and pom.xml, the structure remained the same.

First try with suggested versions then you can ramp them up once you are sure that it is working.

Comment: for now it worked thanks, but now I am getting this error :Request method 'POST' not supported

Comment: Feel free to open a new question for a new issue.
Just make sure you debug it first and share with people your findings so your question does not get automatically closed due to low investigation on your side.

Comment: Hello, the solution you given used it i replaced the tomcat 10 with 9  the error was solved and I changed the path url in controller class so that also worked. Thank you for the solution.

Comment: cool, great job :)